# AWS AppSync XRay Tracing Context not sharing with Auth Lambda

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-xray

I have a AWS AppSync endpoint configured with auth lambda. Also, X-Ray was enabled in both AppSync and  Lambda. When I make a request to AppSync endpoint I can see both traces as separate segments. Not as a one trace. How can I make it as one trace?